# sync framework call two scope within one application

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, winrt-async

I am building a Windows RT store app connecting with SQL server from client side database, and using sync framework to sync data between the two. Two scopes are defined:

- 1) DefaultScope: include all tables and all columns
- 2) TemplateScope:    all tables and some of them has filter clause
  (filter by id etc)

I run the provision script to provision sql server database and generate the server and client side code, and it works now, but only for one scope. 
For example, if I start the sync using DefaultScope, the client database is generated and data is download, everything works. but If the templateScope is used after that, the error "Scope info not found" is returned.
If I start from TemplateScope, then it worked.
I checked the server side and client side database, both scope info looks fine.

Any thoughts?